# Why Does Public web service return 200 OK but no JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am attempting to call this web service: `http://www.civicapps.org/datasets/restaurant-inspections`

Here's my code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                function showInspections() {
                    var data = $.ajax({
                                type : 'GET',
                                url : '//api.civicapps.org/restaurant-inspections/',
                                async : false,
                                dataType : 'json',
                                success: function(data){
                                    if(data.status == "ok"){
                                    alert(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            });     
                        }
                showInspections();
            });
        </script>
```

Firebug Net>XHR shows "200 Status OK" and yet there is no response with the JSON data.  Likewise, Console tab shows the same GET request and status but the text for it is in red.

Questions:

- Am I failing to receive the response data in JSON due to cross-domain issues i.e. the data should be sent in JSONP rather than JSON?  If so, is there a way to get around this solely from my end, assuming the response will not be sent in JSONP?
- What does the red text in Firebug console indicate?

Comment: You are correct -- you MUST use JSONP when accessing another domain.

Comment: yes you have to use jsonp no doubt. but what do you get in alert(data);

Comment: But if they do not return the response in JSONP, only JSON, is there any way I can still make this work on my own absent receiving JSONP?

Comment: You will need a proxy (server script on your own domain) which fill fetch the data for you.

Comment: @max7 no.  If they don't return JSONP, and they don't use `Access-Control` headers, you'll have to get the content from server-side code of your own.

Comment: thanks for the info; I'm using XAMPP for this (not in production).  With this in mind, If anyone can point me to a resource regarding how to write a server-side script under this circumstances that would allow me to receive the JSON, I would be very grateful.

Comment: A JSON proxy in PHP can be as simple as `<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');

echo file_get_contents('http://api.civicapps.org/restaurant-inspections');

?>` (asuming no POST data is needed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Am I failing to receive the response data in JSON due to cross-domain issues i.e. the data should be sent in JSONP rather than JSON?**

Yes. JSONP is actually very different than "JSON" (i.e. an AJAX request that returns JSON-formatted data). Even though the responses look very similar and the implementation in jQuery is very similar (just add a 'p'!), the actual architecture of JSONP is very different. In fact, JSONP is not even AJAX (if by AJAX you mean something that uses `XMLHttpRequest`). JSONP gets around cross-domain issues by using a trick involving a dynamically generated `<script>` element.

**If so, is there a way to get around this solely from my end, assuming the response will not be sent in JSONP?**

Fortunately, no. While this may be unfortunate for *you*, it's fortunate for the web. Because if you could get around cross-domain issues from the client side, the web would be far less secure. Imagine you went to my website and some hidden JavaScript downloaded all your new emails from Gmail, parsed them, then sent them to my server. That would be possible if not for the same-origin policy.

JSONP is nice because it offers a workaround for cross-origin requests that services can opt-in to. If a service wants to be accessible cross-domain, then it can be written in JSONP. This prevents unwitting cross-domain services while allowing for services to volunteer cross-domain availability.

**What does the red text in Firebug console indicate?**

It probably indicates a violation of the same-origin policy.

Comment: fantastic answer, thanks very much for confirming in detail what I thought to be the case.  I learned a lot!